# How to count the anonymous pages and shared pages for a process in Linux using kernel module

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

I am trying to find the resident set size of a c program running on Linux os (ubuntu 14.04). I get the PID of the running C program and pass it to a custom kernel module. The kernel module figures out the `*task` and extracts the `*mm` pointer. Then I loop through all the `VM areas` and in each `VM area` I again loop through each page aligned `virtual addresses` and request a `page_walk(virtual addresses)` to get the `pte` structure of type `pte_t`. Then I used the `pte_preset()` function to check the existence of the actual physical page in the RAM.

The issues I am facing are as follows:

The `rss` value does not match with the value shown in `htop` or `top`. Although the value I have calculated does increase proportionally as the test C program accesses more memory (using some array accessing).

I have found that the `rss` value of `htop` application gives the same result as given by the `get_mm_struct()` function call provided by the Linux kernel itself.

```
static inline unsigned long get_mm_rss(struct mm_struct *mm)
{
    return get_mm_counter(mm, MM_FILEPAGES) +
        get_mm_counter(mm, MM_ANONPAGES) +
        get_mm_counter(mm, MM_SHMEMPAGES);
}
```

My query is how to count or detect these anonymous pages and shared pages? What are bits that need to be checked?

Thank You !

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is to realize that the count is in an array. Try:

```
static inline unsigned long get_mm_rss(struct mm_struct *mm) 
{
    int k;
    unsigned long count = 0;
    for(k = 0; k < NR_MM_COUNTERS; k++) {
         long len = atomic_long_read(&mm->rss_stat.count[k]);
         if(len < 0)  
              len = 0;         
         count += len;
    }

}
```

## Walking Physical Pages

You need to set up mm_walk struct with your call backs for *pte* and *pmd* (driven by whether or not HUGETABLES are used in the kernel) to walk through the physical pages.

For example:

[`show_smap`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/ident/show_smap) uses this:

```
    struct mm_walk smaps_walk = {
        .pmd_entry = smaps_pte_range,
#ifdef CONFIG_HUGETLB_PAGE
        .hugetlb_entry = smaps_hugetlb_range,
#endif
        .mm = vma->vm_mm,
    };
```

after setting up the call backs.

Comment: Thanks! But I am looking for a solution that should not use `atomic_long_read` or  `get_mm_rss` function. I need to use the `page_walk` somehow to achieve the goal (which is to calculate total physical pages )

Comment: aaah ! I understand, you should be able to modify this to do a page_walk

Comment: could you please explain a bit more? I did not understand your procedure